# How can I use FileProvider to share a Image file

Tags: android

How can I use FileProvider to share a Image file.
My app has a image file in the files/attach directory that I want to share the file. I am using a FileProvider to get Uri to share. However, I get a " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException".

```
private void shareNote() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareNote.getTitle());
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareNote.getTitle());
        intent.setType("image/*");
        File attachFile = new File(shareFile.getFilePath()); 
        //FileProvider.getUriForFile() throws a "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException" Exception.
        Uri attachUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.demoapp.rs.mynotebook.fileprovider", attachFile);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachUri);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        getContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.demoapp.rs.mynotebook">
<application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application ...>
    <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.demoapp.rs.mynotebook.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

filepaths.xml

```
<paths>
    <files-path name="ifiles"  path="attach/"/>
    <external-path name="ifiles" path="attach/" />
</paths>
```

the share image file is at directory "/data/data/com.demoapp.rs.mynote/files/attach/F2000001.png"
the Exception detials:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root
>   that contains
>   /data/data/com.demoapp.rs.mynote/files/attach/F2000001.png
>               at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:678)
>               at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:377)
>               at com.demoapp.rs.component.ShareNoteDialog.shareNote(ShareNoteDialog.java:107)
>               at com.demoapp.rs.component.ShareNoteDialog.access$000(ShareNoteDialog.java:29)
>               at com.demoapp.rs.component.ShareNoteDialog$1.onItemClick(ShareNoteDialog.java:72)
>   ...

Answer (score 0):

Then I modify the code like this:

```
 private void shareNote() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareNote.getTitle());
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareNote.getTitle());
        intent.setType("image/*");

//        File attachFile = new File(shareFile.getFilePath());
//        Uri attachUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.demoapp.rs.mynotebook.fileprovider", attachFile);
//        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachUri);
        Uri attachFileUri = Uri.parse("content://com.demoapp.rs.mynotebook.fileprovider/ifiles/F2000001.png");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachFileUri);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Then I send a Email successfull, but the email does not has the shared image file as attach.

Answer (score 0):

And I modify the code again.
I use the original Java code, and modify the filepaths.xml file like this:

```
<paths>
    <files-path name="ifiles"  path="attach/"/>
    <!--<external-path name="ifiles" path="attach/" />-->
</paths>
```

Then I can send email, and I can see the attach file and the file size at the send email userinterface!

But after I open the received email, has no attach file. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I use the FileProvider, AbstractFileProvider, and the configuration in AndroidManifest.xml from  https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/Files , and it works. But there's some email servers can't get the shared file still, when some email servers are OK. I don't know why.